# How to download an Interactive Report as a Word (.doc) file?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I am new to Oracle Apex 5.1, and I have been asked to implement a button that when clicked, the user gets (downloads) a `.doc` file of an Interactive report.

I have noticed that the Interactive Report gives you the option to download it as `.pdf`, `.xls`, and so, but I need it to be a Word `(.doc)` file.

In addition, the file must be in a specific format (with heading, indentation, font, etc.) that I was given (as a template) in a Word file.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Additional Information:** I was able to open the template `(.doc)` file in NotePad++ and get the `<html>` version of it, so I could edit it in both NotePad++ and Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up finding information in this page: http://davidsgale.com/apex-how-to-download-a-file/ and I wrote this code:

```
declare
l_clob clob;

begin
l_clob := null;

sys.htp.init;
sys.owa_util.mime_header('application/vnd.ms-word', FALSE,'utf-8');
sys.htp.p('Content-length: ' || sys.dbms_lob.getlength( l_clob ));
sys.htp.p('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="test_file.doc"' );
sys.owa_util.http_header_close;

sys.htp.p(SET_DOC_HEADER);
sys.htp.p(SET_TABLE_HEADER);
sys.htp.p(ADD_TABLE_ENTRY("arguments"));
sys.htp.p(SET_TABLE_FOOTER);

sys.wpg_docload.download_file(l_clob);
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

exception when others then
--sys.htp.prn('error: '||sqlerrm);
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
end;
```

It works, but I had to create functions in the SQL Workshop because writting a table in `html` is really long.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best actually to do that is APEX OFFICE PRINT(AOP) but isn't free licence.

otherwise you can check this solution

[How do we export a ms-word (or rtf) document (from a web browser) to generated by pl/sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974454/how-do-we-export-a-ms-word-or-rtf-document-from-a-web-browser-to-generated-b)